# jQuery on keypress trigger button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons:

```
$('#prev').click(function() {
   // some code
});

$('#next').click(function() { 
  // some other code
});
```

what I now want to do is adding a `.keypress()` handler to the site which triggers on `arrow-left` the `#prev` click and for `arrow-right` it triggers `#next`. Problem is how can I add this handler?

Comment: So add a keypress handler and look at the keycode.

Comment: You might want a `keyup` event (http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Make sure you attach to the document or something that will actually have focus. Otherwise your key events won't be fired as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `keydown` event and catch the left/right arrow key code.

If left/right arrow are pressed trigger the according button, arrow codes:

> 37 - left
>
> 38 - up
>
> 39 - right
>
> 40 - down

Code:

```
$('#prev').click(function () {
    alert('prev');
});

$('#next').click(function () {
    alert('next');
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $('#prev').click();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $('#next').click();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6CYXH/